# Push VS Upgrade packages

Tags: apex, managed-package, isv, postinstall

I was setting up postInstall scripts and noticed that there is a condition that checks for if it is an upgrade or push. My understanding was that the method of installation should be irrelevant but obviously I'm missing something here. Can someone please advise what the potential differences between the two would be?

```
public void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
            if(context.previousVersion() == null) {
    [...]
            }else{
                if(context.isUpgrade()) {
                }
                if(context.isPush()) {

                }
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of push upgrades there is no way to choose for which users package would be installed, it would trigger 'Admin Only' mode and that's it.

But when upgrading package by directly typing url on subscriber org, you are prompted with a dialog to chose among 'Admin Only', 'All Users' and 'Specific Profiles'.

So in push upgrade mode ordinary users wouldn't get permissions to access some maybe required objects, and you could bypass this by assigning permission sets to them as a part of post installation script in that context.isPush() branch.